# socket timeout value for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm writing iPhone application which uses sockets and uses `CFSocketConnectToAddress` for creating sockets. I need to specify socket timeout in seconds. What is best timeout value in seconds for iPhone/iPod which uses wifi/3g/edge connection ?

Sample code:

```
#define SOCKET_TIMEOUT_VALUE ?
CFSocketRef sock_id = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, PF_INET,  SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, kCFSocketNoCallBack, NULL, NULL) ; 
struct sockaddr_in addr4;
memset(&addr4, 0, sizeof(addr4));
addr4.sin_len = sizeof(addr4);
addr4.sin_family = PF_INET;
addr4.sin_port = htons([[hostValue port_number] intValue]);
inet_pton(AF_INET, inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)host_name->h_addr_list[0]), &addr4.sin_addr);
CFDataRef addr = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (void*)&addr4, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
int retVal = CFSocketConnectToAddress(sock_id, addr, SOCKET_TIMEOUT_VALUE);
if (retVal != 0)
{
    // Failed to Connect!
    errorNumber = FAILED_CONNECT ; 
    CFRelease(addr) ;
    CFRelease(sock_id) ;
    goto shutdown2; 
}
```

[Apple documentation for CFSocketConnectToAddress](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/Reference/reference.html)

EDIT:

App will have few socket creations same time for different hosts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given typical circumstances, a socket will connect within an imperceptibly small amount of time (for the user). Sometimes that isn't the case. The structure of your application (specifically, the threading) should account for this.

The foremost rule is that you shouldn't block the main thread while waiting for the socket to connect. Show an indeterminate progress indicator that you're trying to connect. Give the user the ability to back up and choose not to proceed.

If you're looking for a numerical answer instead of a design answer, I frequently toss in sixty seconds.

Comment: OK, i'm using gcd blocks to not block UI thread. I chosen to use 30s timeout value. Thanks for you answer.